# xpath help can't get the text?

Tags: html, web-services, xhtml, xpath

I am unable to get the text from this website: http://mp3bear.com...so now I just want to get the title of the song that is displayed on it.. here is what i wrote as the code:

//table/tr[2]/td[2]

so now I want to get second row from second column... it doesn't display anything.... is there any thing special when

Comment: @tushar 1: Selecting a node is the first part. Then you need to do something with that node: getting the string value with the proper DOM method i.e.

Comment: possible duplicate of [if you know xpath then please help?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5287283/if-you-know-xpath-then-please-help)

Answer (score 2):

I can't find any table element on this site, the tables are constructed with divs.

Therefore the expression for the second row of the second column of the table is.

```
//div[@id='listwrap']/div[3]/div[2]
```

There are some xpath implementations that don't allow indexing of child elements in this manner. In this case you could use

```
//div[@id='listwrap']/div[position()='3']/div[position()='2']
```

Edit:

In that case you need this expression:

```
//div[@id='listwrap']/div[3]/div[2]/a/text()
```

as the title is contained in a 'a' element and you use the xpath function text() to get the text value of the 'a' element

tested in firepath.

Comment: I specifically want the title of the songs please help me thanks